# My sony vaio pcg-61611L will start, and be working perfectly fine, and then stop with a blank screen

Tags: sony-vaio

Computer will start, and work perfectly normally for a few minutes, and then the screen will go blank and the computer will stop communicating with the hard drive and become completely unresponsive. It has nothing to do with the software on the hard drive. It will do it at any time, including while looking at the bios or before booting. After it crashes, it will turn on but not load the bios or anything, and the screen will remain completely dark. I can get it to boot if I first unplug it and remove the battery. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two possible causes which come to mind are bad software or bad CPU fan. Since you have ruled out the bad software I think the problem is caused by the CPU fan not working and hence the CPU overheating.

I think this is a common problem with VAIO. My cs17g vaio had the same problem and I replaced the fan twice before it started working correctly.

Comment: Thank you. I have been booting the computer with a linux mint thumb drive, and at first there was no difference, but after a while it started working better, but still stops randomly. My previous statement that it has nothing to do with the software appears to be only partially true. The CPU fan theory sounds perfectly reasonable judging by some of the other symptoms. I have been attempting to reinstall the bios in the hopes that it will help, do you think that could be helpful? I think you're right about the fan, though.

Comment: I think you can differentiate between software and hardware by using a Linux live cd to boot. Do not insert the thumb drive during this test. Browse through a while while on the live cd boot and check how it goes.
From what you said I kinda think the thumb drive boot is not integrating with the laptop hardware very well. You could try updating your bios.